# How to integrate go_router with seo_renderer?

Tags: flutter, seo

I am using go_router for my project. Recently I wanted to integrate seo_renderer into my project.

https://pub.dev/packages/go_router

https://pub.dev/packages/seo_renderer

However, the examples show that these 2 libraries are not compatible with each other.

```
// seo_renderer:
runApp(
  RobotDetector(
    debug: true, // you can set true to enable robot mode
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      navigatorObservers: [seoRouteObserver],
    ),
  ),
);

// go_router
final _router = GoRouter(
   observers: [seoRouteObserver], // Not working.
   routes: [ ...]
);
// navigatorObservers is setted to null.
MaterialApp.router(
   routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
   routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
   title: 'GoRouter Example',
);
```

Can anyone give me an example?